# ヒューマノイドではないキャラクターをIKで動かしたい

Tags: unity3d

UnityでのIKは、マニュアルによれば「[Mecanim で 正しく設定されたアバターのある ヒューマノイドキャラクターにおいてサポートされます](http://docs.unity3d.com/ja/current/Manual/InverseKinematics.html)」とのことですが、IKまたはIKに似た動作を、ヒューマノイドではないキャラクターで行う方法はないでしょうか？

例えば「ショベルカーの先端部分を移動させると、それに伴ってアーム部分が動く」というようなことをUnity上で実現したいと考えております。

Comment: @見習い戦士　さん、ご回答ありがとうございます。GenericIKの実装予定はまだまだ先のようですので、Humanoidとしてインポートする方法を試してみようと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GenericIKは将来的に実装される予定です。
ttp://unity3d.com/jp/unity/roadmap

どうしてもGenericでIKを使いたい場合、現状ではHumanoidとして
インポートするしかありません。この場合、ショベルカーはHumanRigボーンを含んでいて、
その一部ボーンにアニメーション用のウェイトが適用されている事になります。

HingeJointで似たような事ができますが、
安定しない上メッシュを別けて設計する必要があります。